# Neo4j index creation on a database

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently trying out Neo4j to see what it can do. My database consists of around 54000 nodes and 10M relationships (2 relationship types) that has been imported using https://github.com/jexp/batch-import from TSV files. What I'm finding out is that there's a need for indexes to get query results in a reasonable time.

One of the typical queries I want to make is to list nodes that are connected with certain type, and the connecting nodes have certain values. Something like:

```
START 
    a=node(*) 
MATCH 
    (a)-[r]->(b) 
WHERE 
    id(a) <> 0 
    AND id(b) <> 0 
    AND type(r) = 'ASSOCIATION' 
    AND a.attr1 = 'value' 
    AND b.attr1 = 'value' 
RETURN 
    a, b LIMIT 200.
```

Naturally this query never completes.

1. With that in mind, what is the easiest method to (batch create?) relationship index for this kind of query on an existing database? And indexes for nodes that have certain attribute values?
2. Is this something that could be done from the web console or at all afterwards? From reading neo4j manual I got the understanding that you'd want to write a custom java implementation that loads the data node-by-node and build the indexes while creating the database. I'd personally like to use python, but the python bindings turned out to be too slow even to import the current db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a specific start?

If not, you can try to index your relationships, then pull them out in your start and then go from there:

```
START 
    specificRelationship=relationship:RelIndex(key='value')
MATCH
    a-[specificRelationship]->b
WHERE
    AND a.attr1 = 'value' 
    AND b.attr1 = 'value' 
RETURN 
    a, b LIMIT 200
```

To answer your questions:

1. You can create any type of index, either on Relationships, or on Nodes, the choice is which you are going to be looking up. I usually see people specificity a Node first, where you can retrieve through a key/value pair based on a separately defined property.
2. I've not done this in Python, but you can load easily in Java, and if you wanted to perform this query, you can do it through the Web Console of Neo4j, or through Java if you'd like to do something with the information.

Comment: (2) Looking from the MySQL side of things, isn't there an option in gremlin to create the index for the existing data? In MySQL you could just do CREATE INDEX command, isn't there a similar way? Looks cumbersome to reload the whole db every time you want an index containing large amounts of data.

Comment: In neo4j, you need to index yourself, it is not something that is automatically done for you.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the batch import source a bit by following http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html#indexing-batchinsert and created the relevant node and edge indexes.


Seems that one can build somekind of index by using gremlin as well (but I didn't know how to do proper filtering in gremlin to get the set of vertices I want instead of g.getVertices() ):
indexKeys = new HashSet<String>();
indexKeys.add("attr1");
index = g.createAutomaticIndex("nodeIndex", Vertex.class, indexKeys);
AutomaticIndexHelper.reIndexElements( g, index, g.getVertices() );